# Good tips for how to connect cables into Mux Shield II?

Tags: hardware, wires, multiplexer

I just got a Mux Shield 2 and got it working as I expected. Now I started to find out how to actually connect the I/O cables to the board. Doesn't seem to be as simple as I thought. I don't want to solder cables into the board for maintenance reasons. So, does anyone have any good tips on how to do this?

[image: Photo of shield]

Comment: if you want plugs, solder plugs onto it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solder 100-mil male headers onto the board, then use 100-mil crimp terminals to connect the wires.

[image: 100-mil male headers]
[image: Female crimp terminals]
[image: Connected]